# Javascript doesn't work with jsf commandButton

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap, jsf, commandbutton

I have this code:

```
<h:commandButton value="Login as Administrator" id="login"
                        data-loading-text="Loading..." class="btn btn-primary"
                        action="#{adminController.loginAdmin}"/>

                    <script>
                         $('#login').on('click', function() {
                            var $btn = $(this).button('loading')
                            // business logic...
                            $btn.button('reset')
                        })
                    </script>
```

I don't know why I can't call my javascript function. No change will show when i click the button, it execute only the action. I have take this script from bootstrap javascript, section button. http://getbootstrap.com/javascript/#buttons

Thanks for help.

Comment: Are you sure the id `login` is unique on your html page?

Comment: Yes, it is unique in the page

Answer (score 0):

As you most likely have a form wrapping the button and the form is a `UINamingContainer`, the ID of the form will be prepended to the one of the button. So the resulting ID in the HTML will be something like `form:login` and that is why the eventlistener is not added to the button.

You have to know that what you write in the XHTML will be parsed by JSF and then a generated HTML will be sent to the user. So what you write is not what you get to see in the browser.

Now you could have a look at the generated HTML to get the actual ID of the button and use that one. But as you are using JSF it is much better to use the builtin attributes of the `h:commandButton`, i.e. `onclick` and specify a JS function there which does the stuff you want to do on click. And maybe you want to use `oncomplete` also to reset the label of the button when the action is finished.

```
<h:commandButton value="Login as Administrator" id="login"
   action="#{adminController.loginAdmin}" onclick="login()"/>

 <script>
   function login() {
     var $btn = $(this).button('loading');
     // business logic...
     $btn.button('reset');
   }
 </script>
```

You should also be aware that `data-loading-text` will not find its way through the JSF parser, so you will not see this property on the generated HTML button.